# IFT application.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, self-learning

Suppose that $f:=(u,v):\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ is $C^2$ and $(x_0,y_0)=f(t_0)$

A) prove that if $f'(t_0)\not=0$ then $u'(t_0)$ and $v'(t_0)$cannot both be zero.

B) if $f'(t_0)\not=0$ show that either there is $C^1$ function $g$ such that $g(x_0)=t_0$ and $u(g(x))=x$ for $x$ near $x_0$ or there is $C^1$ function $h$ such that $h(y_0)=t_0$ and $u(g(y))=y$ for $y$ near $y_0$

---

I guess, I need to use Implicit Function thm. But I dont know how to use this therem to solve these two parts. I just have been starting to learn this theorem by myself. Please explicitly show me. Thank you :)

Comment: Where it says $g(tx_0)$, should it merely say $g(x_0)$?

Comment: I dont understand  what you are trying to say, sorry. @EricAuld pease can you clearly show these two parts below answe box?

Comment: I think it is a typo where you write "$g(tx_0)$".

Comment: Sorry, I saw this. Thank you for warning @EricAuld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *inverse* function theorem.

For part A, you have to show that $f'(t)$ is just the vector consisting of $(u'(t), v'(t))$. You can show this quickly from the definition of the
derivative, but it depends how your book defines it.  For instance, if the definition for $v$ is the derivative of $f(t)$ is

$$\lim_ {t\to t_o} \left \| \frac{f(t) -  f(t_0)} {t} -v \right \|=0,$$

then it just requires knowing that a vector goes to zero iff it goes to zero in each component.

Part B is really just the definition of the implicit function theorem. A function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ can be thought of as two functions $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$, which are the functions in the components. Read what the criteria are for applying the inverse function theorem, and apply it!

Comment: I know the definition that $\lim_{t\to t_0} \vert \vert \frac{f(t)-f(t_0)-\nabla f(t).t}{t}\vert\vert=0$

Comment: Then if $f'(t_0)\not=0$, then $\nabla f(t_0)\not=0$. That's either $u'(t_o)$ or $v'(t_0)\not=0$

Comment: Is this enough to prove part a? I understand correct what you mean. Is it?

Comment: Yes, perhaps they want you to show why $\nabla f(t_0) \neq 0 \Rightarrow u'(t_0)\neq 0$ or $v'(t_0)\neq 0$.

Comment: How? This detail might be important for me to get sufficient grade from my exam. Please can you show this? Because I am at beginner level and self-studying, so I could not show this in detail.sorry:(

Comment: Hint: you can easily get it from your form into the form I mention above, where $v = \nabla f (t)$.

Comment: Now, I am writing for part-b what I understand. Let's define a function $F(x,t)=u(t)-x$ I am finding that $DF(t)=\begin {pmatrix} -1 && u'(t)\end{pmatrix}$. Since $\nabla F(x_0, t_0)\not=0$, by IFT, the function $t_0=g(x_0)$ exists.

Comment: That is a fine way to do it. What you have done is to derive the inverse function theorem from the implicit function theorem.

Comment: $\vert\vert \frac{f(t)-f(t_0)}{t}-\nabla f(t)\vert\vert \le \vert\vert \frac{f(t)-f(t_0)}{t}\vert\vert+ \vert\vert \nabla f(t)\vert\vert \le \vert \nabla f(t)\vert =\vert (u'(t), v'(t))$ since $f'(t)\not\to 0$ so $u', v'$ not equal to zero. (I guess, I wrote trivial things, sorry)

Comment: I dont know, I did part -b by using previous examples I solved.

Comment: You should stop at the first step (no triangle inequality) and notice that this is the same as the single-dimension derivative, applied in each component.

Comment: That's, $\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{u(t)-u(t_0)}{t}-u'(t)=0$

Comment: As you see, I tried, but I could not do some things. And I have no one to teach these. Please I am glad you to complete my drawbacks. Thank you for all helping:)